# Pinterest Rich Pins meta tags for product

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, meta, pinterest, pins

I need to generate following meta tags for Pinterest rich pins:
standard price - so Pinterest knows if the product on sale,
currency
current price
product color

I am confused by Pinterest docs:
developers.pinterest.com/rich_pins_product/

There is an example:

```
<meta property="og:price:amount" content="15.00" />
<meta property="og:price:standard_amount" content="20.00" />
<meta property="og:price:currency" content="USD" />
<meta property="product:color" content="Aqua" >
```

But below the example their docs mentioning:

```
product:price:amount
product:price:currency
```

I found these meta tags on facebook:
developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/object-type/product/

I am not sure which tags should I use.

I tried to use these tags:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Elicia Shirt"/>

<meta property="og:image" content="http://anf.scene7.com/is/image/anf/anf_78498_01_prod1?$productImageSocial-anf$"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Abercrombie & Fitch"/> 
<meta property="og:description" content="Classic and supersoft, button-down closure, front chest pockets, Easy Fit, Imported&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;100% cotton"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.abercrombie.com/shop/a-us/p/elicia-shirt-2828085"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="product"/>
<meta property="og:price:standard_amount" content="58.0"/> 
<meta property="og:price:amount" content="39.0"/>
<meta property="og:price:currency" content="USD"/>
<meta property="og:availability" content="instock"/> 
<meta property="product:color" content="WHITE"/>
```

and validate with Pinterest tool
http://awesomescreenshot.com/0d13m8gp0b

It doesn't seem to get the standard price and color, and shows me price, availability and currency twice.

I would appreciate any help on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got Response from Pinterest support.

They are scraping Schema.org tags first and then looking for open graph tags. I had Schema.org tags for page description,url, etc. and Pinterest verifying tools was also trying to fetch price and other values for my product which isn't there.

Pinterest support suggested to add the rest of Schema.org values for my product.

Hopefully it would be helpful for someone here.
Good luck!